# Form with image upload not working in Django

Tags: django, forms, image, upload

I am trying to get this form to work but I seem to be missing something.  This is what I have so far.  When I submit the form nothing happens, no error message, just a blank form.

**views.py** here is my views file.  It only has this one view

```
def add_book_view(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddBookForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('books:book_list')

    else:
        form = AddBookForm()
    return render(request, 'settings/add_book.html', {'form' : form})
```

**form** here is my form.  I have stripped out the css because I apparently have too much code and not enough "description".  I am really trying to get this solved.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  Title:
  <input class="settings-form-input" type="text" name="title" maxlength="256"
  required="" id="id_title">
  Author(s):
  <input class="settings-form-input" type="text" name="authors" maxlength="256"
  required="" id="id_authors">
  Genre:
    <select name="genre" id="id_genre">
      <option value="0" selected="">None</option>
      <option value="1">Action-Adventure</option>
      <option value="2">Autobigraphy</option>
      <option value="3">Biography</option>
      etc...
    </select>
  <br/>
    Book Cover:
  <input type="file" name="book_cover" accept="image/*" required="" id="id_book_cover">
  <br/><br/>
    Description:
  <textarea class="settings-form-textarea" name="description" required=""
  id="id_description"></textarea>
  <input type="hidden" name="added_by" id="id_added_by" value="{{ user.first_name}}
  {{ user.last_name }}">
  <input type="submit" class="form-button" value="Add Book">
</form>
```

**models.py** This is my models file.  This form isn't letting me post because it says I have too much code and not enough details so now I am just trying to get more "details" in.

```
class Book(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
   authors = models.CharField(max_length=256, default=None)
   GENRE = [
       ('0', 'None'),
       ('1', 'Action-Adventure'),
       ('2', 'Autobigraphy'),
       ('3', 'Biography'),
       ('4', 'Classic'),
       ('5', 'Drama'),
       ('6', 'Fantasy'),
       ('7', 'Fiction'),
       ('8', 'Historical'),
       ('9', 'Mystery'),
       ('10', 'Non-Fiction'),
       ('11', 'Romance'),
       ('12', 'Science-Fiction'),
   ]
   genre = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=GENRE, default='0')
   book_cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='covers/', default=None)
   description = models.TextField(default=None)
   added_by = models.CharField(max_length=256, default=None)
   date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT  = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I have pillow installed in my environment.  It says I cant post without adding more information but I don't really know what to say.  I actually had this working and I am not aware of any changes but now it does not work.  So it must be close.

Comment: Print the `form` `errors` if the `form` is not valid and see what it points to. `if form.is_valid(): form.save()...` `else: print(form.errors)`.

Comment: go to the admin panel and check the form. if the form is saved check the book_cover field

Comment: I had a field in my forms.py that wasn't in the template form so the form was missing a required field and wasn't valid.  Thanks for the help!